# How to retrieve contact image Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I try to use the contacts list in my Xamarin.Form application. I use

```
Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> contact = await Xamarin.Essentials.Contacts.GetAllAsync(token);
```

but Contact doesn't contain a field with image.
What can I use instead?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, Xamarin.Essentials Contact class does not include photo. You would have to write code per platform, in each platform-specific project. For Android, [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43757530/199364).

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: You could use the dependency service to do the specific implementations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction For Android, you could use the Contacts ContentProvider.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/blob/live/docs/android/platform/content-providers/contacts-contentprovider.md